# css images moving together and not individually

Tags: jquery, html, css

Whenever I try and move the images, they are moving together instead of individually even though I specifically identify the id.

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    background:url(../images/imgs/backgrnd.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:mainText;
    src:url(../font/HelveticaNeueLTPro-UltLtEx.otf);
}

#holder {
    background:url(../images/imgs/rectangle%20and%20letters.png) no-repeat;
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:11.2em;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    list-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#nextarrow {
    margin-left:350px;
}


<section id="cont"> <!-- main content wrapper -->
    <div id="holder">
        <ul id="imagelist"> <!-- image cycle: prev/next -->
            <li><img src="images/imgs/iPhone.png" width="256" height="256" border="0"></li>
            <li><img src="images/imgs/websitesimg.png" width="289" height="187" border="0"></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</section>

<div id="arrows">
    <img src="images/imgs/rightarrow.png" id="nextarrow" width="15" height="130" alt="ja" />
    <img src="images/imgs/leftarrow.png" id="prevarrow" width="15" height="130" alt="la" />
</div>
```

the images inside div id="arrows" is what I'm trying to move and even though i specify #nextarrow {   it's moving the entire  I only want to move one image at a time by either id or using first/last child

Comment: I think you need to switch the images, so left is first, then right. Here is a jsfiddle explaining what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/HdA24/1/ Please tell me if this works! I am interested in knowing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images appear to be inverse. If you switch the order of the images, it will affect what happens next. Let me break it down a little bit for you. If the first image is the right arrow and the second image is the left arrow, you will have two arrows pointing at one another: -> <- 
Now what CSS does, when you decide to give the "next arrow" a margin-left of anything, will shift the entire contents of the right arrow along with whatever is after it.

So again, you put the right arrow first, meaning you called for the right arrow to move along with whatever is after that arrow. Now, if you wanted to keep the right arrow on the left and the left arrow on the right but still separate the two, you would just call for CSS to shift the "prev arrow" like this :

```
#prevarrow {
margin-left:350px;
```

}

and this will actually shift the arrows to look like this: ->           <-
However, lets go with another scenario: what if you swapped the images? So now it would look something like this: <- -> 
Well, as it may seem, if you were to use the exact same CSS code as you have posted:

```
#nextarrow {
    margin-left:350px;
}
```

it would only shift the right arrow and anything after that right arrow, which in this case is nothing. But vice versa, if you were to use the CSS with "prevarrow" now in this case of it being flipped, it would move both of the arrows. I encourage you to swap the images and see what happens with both of the above CSS codes. You will notice that one will shift the contents of the entire line over while the other one will simply just shift one arrow. Again, my jsfiddle will also explain what happened: http://jsfiddle.net/HdA24/2/

Comment: I just updated it so the jsfiddle can explain what I have said above but with photos. Take a look at that and let me know if that makes any sense. Also, if it makes more sense, do me a favor in click the green arrow next to my answer.

Comment: yup that helped a lot, tested on own code and works - +1 and answer

Answer (score 2):

Images are [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements), which means as you add margin to the right arrow, which is ironically appearing on the left, the image immediately beside it is going to be affected by that padding/margin.

I would recommend taking some time to learn about the [box model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

Comment: no that has nothing to do with @ buddhistbeast, i just added them in the wrong way. Thanks James, just had to add a line break to separate them

Comment: i havn't touched the order, James is right - the images are inline. why would the order have anything to do with it? It's just an image, the problem was whenever I tried to move one of the images individually it moved both.

Comment: Which is because you were calling #nextarrow, which was behind the left arrow, causing it to shift both the left and right arrow. If you put the arrows back in order, you would automatically fix the problem because then you wouldn't be trying to set the margin for the wrong arrow... Just switch the images and it should be correct.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just interested in knowing whether it was the line breaks or the order of the images. I apologize if I am coming off like a jerk.

Comment: no no it's fine, i feel like a jerk since i'm the one asking the q. Just tested and your way works fine, just didn't make sense to me why the order would matter

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry i should have re-ordered my code in a more logical and i either would have seen the problem or it would have made it easier for you to answer, i apologize for second-guessing, i should have tested before saying anything

Comment: It's all good man, I have been in your exact same shoes! Just be open minded about suggestions, some can be ten times easier than others!